# Can't install GeoServer WPS, missing files

Tags: geoserver, installation, wps

I'm following the instructions step by step from [GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/remote-wps/install_geoserver.html) to build a GeoServer with WPS remote plugin but at some point in the instructions in the deploy and configure

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/remote-wps/install_geoserver.html#deploy-and-configure-geoserver

During this command:
`mvn clean install -Pwps,wps-remote,importer,security,rest-ext -DskipTests`

It starts complaining about missing files. What am I missing? I'm starting same as the guide on a CentoOS 7 clean minimal installation.

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ gs-gwc ---
[INFO] Compiling 43 source files to /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[33,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[34,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[35,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1214,73] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWC
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[26,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[27,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[18,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[19,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[20,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[22,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[27,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class HttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[47,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[49,68] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[53,68] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[71,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[135,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[139,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[187,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[252,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletRequest
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[13,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[16,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[89,38] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[89,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[114,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[191,48] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[215,61] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[196,32] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy.ResponseWrapper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[201,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GwcServiceProxy.ResponseWrapper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[17,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[18,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[26,48] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class HttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[30,57] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[49,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[57,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[73,26] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[170,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[766,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWC
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[767,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWC
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1223,36] error: incompatible types: FakeHttpServletRequest cannot be converted to HttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1228,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWC
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1247,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWC
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[428,61] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GeoServerTileLayer
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[622,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GeoServerTileLayer
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[623,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GeoServerTileLayer
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/wms/CachingWebMapService.java:[119,45] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class CachingWebMapService
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/wms/CachingWebMapService.java:[166,53] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class CachingWebMapService
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[94,49] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[104,57] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[113,57] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[124,49] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[100,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable responseWrapper of type GwcServiceProxy.ResponseWrapper
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[200,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[205,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[219,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[224,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[28,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[58,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[58,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class FakeHttpServletResponse
/root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[75,36] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 59 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GeoServer ......................................... SUCCESS [1.148s]
[INFO] Core Platform Module .............................. SUCCESS [4.443s]
[INFO] Open Web Service Module ........................... SUCCESS [5.183s]
[INFO] Main Module ....................................... SUCCESS [17.972s]
[INFO] GeoServer Security Modules ........................ SUCCESS [0.138s]
[INFO] GeoServer JDBC Security Module .................... SUCCESS [4.204s]
[INFO] GeoServer LDAP Security Module .................... SUCCESS [3.779s]
[INFO] Web Coverage Service Module ....................... SUCCESS [2.257s]
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 1.0 Module ................... SUCCESS [5.308s]
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 1.1 Module ................... SUCCESS [5.340s]
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 2.0 Module ................... SUCCESS [7.309s]
[INFO] Web Feature Service Module ........................ SUCCESS [9.957s]
[INFO] Web Map Service Module ............................ SUCCESS [11.875s]
[INFO] KML support for GeoServer ......................... SUCCESS [6.140s]
[INFO] GeoWebCache (GWC) Module .......................... FAILURE [3.186s]
[INFO] REST Support Module ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST Configuration Service Module ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Web Modules ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Core UI Module .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WMS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GWC UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WFS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Demos Module ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WCS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI Modules ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI Core Module ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI JDBC Module ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI LDAP Module ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST UI Module .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Extensions .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Processing Service parent ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Processing Service Module ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Processing Service GUI ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Data Importer ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Importer Core Module .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Importer Web UI Module ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Importer REST Api Module .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Community Space ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST plugin community module ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Processing Service - Remote processes invocation  SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Web Application ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web process status sharing with Hazelcast ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Security Extension Modules .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Security Extension Web Modules .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Importer Berkley DB Persistence Module ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:29.120s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 01 09:24:30 GMT 2019
[INFO] Final Memory: 380M/741M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project gs-gwc: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[33,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[34,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[35,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1214,73] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWC
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[26,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[27,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[18,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[19,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[20,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[22,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[27,40] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class HttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[47,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[49,68] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[53,68] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[71,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[135,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[139,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[187,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletRequest.java:[252,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[13,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[16,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[89,38] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[89,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[114,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[191,48] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[215,61] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[196,32] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy.ResponseWrapper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[201,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GwcServiceProxy.ResponseWrapper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[17,20] error: package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[18,25] error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[26,48] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class HttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[30,57] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[49,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[57,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[73,26] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[170,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[766,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWC
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[767,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWC
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1223,36] error: incompatible types: FakeHttpServletRequest cannot be converted to HttpServletRequest
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1228,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWC
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/GWC.java:[1247,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWC
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[428,61] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GeoServerTileLayer
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[622,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GeoServerTileLayer
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GeoServerTileLayer.java:[623,12] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GeoServerTileLayer
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/wms/CachingWebMapService.java:[119,45] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class CachingWebMapService
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/wms/CachingWebMapService.java:[166,53] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class CachingWebMapService
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[94,49] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[104,57] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[113,57] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/layer/GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.java:[124,49] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider.RESTConverterHelper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[100,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable responseWrapper of type GwcServiceProxy.ResponseWrapper
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[200,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[205,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[219,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/dispatch/GwcServiceProxy.java:[224,8] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[28,50] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[58,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[58,69] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] class FakeHttpServletResponse
[ERROR] /root/geoserver.src/src/gwc/src/main/java/org/geoserver/gwc/FakeHttpServletResponse.java:[75,36] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :gs-gwc
```

Comment: could you not download the pre-compiled jars from https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/ rather than building from source. If you must build from source then we need to know which branch/tag you are building and some more info about java version and maven setup

Comment: I never installed GeoServer before and I found this step by step instruction so I was following them. As I said I'm following the exact same instructions in the website, so everything is the same with the difference that my `java -version 1.8.0_221` instead of `1.8.0_65` as the first link is broken and in the repo I found out that there is the installer for version `1.8.0_221` so I installed that one.

Comment: to install GeoServer - goto http://geoserver.org/release/stable/ and fetch the platform independent binary and unpack it somewhere. There are instructions at https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/index.html#installation

Comment: OK, I'll try to follow those instructions. should I follow the instructions for Linux Binary or the web archive? is going t be a wms web service on a linux machine